# files.get and .getRequestFactory cannot be resolved

Tags: android, google-drive-api

I'm trying to get the metadata of a file in my Google Drive through the fileID but I'm running into some problems using `files().get` and `getRequestFactory()`.

Specifically I'm looking at [this](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/get) and on the sample it shows the line

`File file = service.files().get(fileID).execute();` and

`HttpResponse resp = service.getRequestFactory().buildGetRequest(new GenericUrl(file.getDownloadUrl())).execute();`

I used these:

```
import com.google.api.client.http.GenericUrl;
import com.google.api.client.http.HttpResponse;
import com.google.api.services.drive.model.File;
```

as stated in the sample and loaded the `com.google.apis:google-api-services-drive:v2-rev168-1.20.0` dependency. But it's still resulting in `Cannot resolve method files()` and `Cannot resolve method getRequestFactory()`,

Can anyone shed some light on this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have recently run my project with these imports / dependencies without problems, try to double-check your situation

```
import com.google.api.client.extensions.android.http.AndroidHttp;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.extensions.android.gms.auth.GoogleAccountCredential;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.extensions.android.gms.auth.UserRecoverableAuthIOException;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException;
import com.google.api.client.http.FileContent;
import com.google.api.client.http.GenericUrl;
import com.google.api.client.json.gson.GsonFactory;
import com.google.api.services.drive.Drive;
import com.google.api.services.drive.DriveScopes;
import com.google.api.services.drive.model.File;
import com.google.api.services.drive.model.FileList;
import com.google.api.services.drive.model.ParentReference;

com.google.api.services.drive NEEDS
    com.google.apis:google-api-services-drive:v2-rev105-1.17.0-rc
com.google.api.client NEEDS
    com.google.api-client:google-api-client-android:1.20.0
com.google.api.client.json.gson NEEDS
   com.google.http-client:google-http-client-gson:1.20.0
```

The chunk above is pulled from this [GitHub test / demo](https://github.com/seanpjanson/GDAADemo). You're welcome to use it (replace the GDAA referencies in MainActivity with 'REST').

Good Luck